# Oracle query which works for Day Light Saving in EST time zone

Tags: oracle, timezone, dst

I am working on an application in which:

- Authentication token has an expiration of 2 hours from its creation
  time.
- Token creation and expiration time stored in DB are local date / time
  (i.e. EST)
- Tokens generated within 2 hours before DST starts, expire in 1 hour
  time as clock moves 1 hour forward.
- For ex: If a token is created at 1:30 AM on 14th March 2021, then its
  creation and expiration time will set in DB as “2021-03-14 01:30:00”
  and “2021-03-14 03:30:00” respectively. Now, suppose DST starts at 2
  PM, server time will be 3:00 at that moment and the token which
  should be valid till 3:30 will now expire at 2:30

currently I am using the query which start failing when day light saving starts in US. The below query is used to fetch active token from DB:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl1  WHERE TOKEN_VALUE = 'xyztoken' AND 
  TOKEN_EXPIRATION > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Is there any way to tweak the above query so that it returns the right result once day light saving start in US.

TOKEN_EXPIRATION and TOKEN_CREATION fields are in `TIMESTAMP`

Comment: How infeasible would it be to store the token creation and expiration time in UTC instead? Fundamentally these are "instants in time" rather than date/time values with a natural time zone, so storing them in UTC would make more sense IMO. Aside from anything else, if you store "1:30am" on the day that a *fall back* transition occurs, you've immediately lost information - is that the first occurrence of 1:30am on that day, or the second?

Comment: "Token creation and expiration time stored in DB are local date / time" What is the data type of the column you are using to store this? Please [edit] your question with the DDL statement for your table and an example DML (`INSERT`) statement for how you are storing the token expiration in the table.

Comment: TOKEN_EXPIRATION and TOKEN_CREATION fields are in TIMESTAMP field and while saving it in DB, I am saving it using java new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your `TOKEN_EXPIRATION` is stored as a `DATE` data type where the date/time represents the time in the `EST` time zone then you can convert it back to a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` using:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl1
WHERE  TOKEN_VALUE = 'xyztoken'
AND    FROM_TZ( CAST( TOKEN_EXPIRATION AS TIMESTAMP ), 'EST5EDT' ) > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

If it is a `TIMESTAMP` column then you can skip the `CAST`:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   tbl1
WHERE  TOKEN_VALUE = 'xyztoken'
AND    FROM_TZ( TOKEN_EXPIRATION, 'EST5EDT' ) > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: `FROM_TZ(CAST(TOKEN_EXPIRATION AS TIMESTAMP), 'EST')` does not work. Verify with `FROM_TZ(CAST(SYSDATE+180 AS TIMESTAMP ), 'EST')` which returns time with  UTC-05 offset but should be UTC-04. Timezone `'EST5EDT'` should work better.

Comment: @MTO does it work fine with TimeStamp field?

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Thanks, updated to use `EST5EDT`.

Comment: @SumitSood Yes, you can skip the `CAST` and just use `FROM_TZ` directly on the column.

Comment: @MTO : Can I use 'America/New_York' instead of 'EST5EDT' as per https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones, 'EST5EDT' seems to deprecated

Comment: @SumitSood If that accurately represents the location used in your database and how the times are stored then, yes. What you should probably do is look at how the data is entered (or the system time zone) and mirror that and if it is `America/New_York` then its all fine; if it is something else then you need to evaluate what your business needs are and how you want to process the data.

Comment: EST5EDT is an old IANA identifier for backwards compatibility only.  It emulates a POSIX TZ string, and thus has all the limitations thereof.  I highly recommend using `America/New_York` if in the US, or whichever locality-based time zone identifier that is applicable.